# Saved InterpolatingFunction behaving badly

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, numerics, interpolation

**Bug introduced in 10 and persists through 12.0 or later**

---

I [created this `InterpolatingFunction`](http://pastebin.com/vQK1U0xZ), and `NIntegrate` gives an absurd result

I load the function and plot its derivative:

```
intfunc = << "intfunc2.m"
Plot[intfunc'[t], {t, 0, 1627577.2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: function derivative plot]

From the curve, the maximum value of the plot is of the order of $10^{-8}$

When I try to integrate this function over the interval, I would've expected a quantity of about an order of $10^{-1}$. Instead I get something very different:

```
NIntegrate[intfunc'[tt], {tt, 0, 1627577.2}]
```

This gives me $-2.6 \times 10^{69}$! Clearly something is wrong in my interpolating function. Any idea what is causing this weird result?

Comment: may be it is a bug. But to be able to make sure, someone needs to see your input file there.

Comment: It is in the link in the first line of the post

Comment: Your link is to a site that is blocked by Norton Security as a malicious web site.

Comment: ugh. Is a file upload site. What would be a suggested place to upload this?

Comment: is the m file so large that you can't simply post the relevant plain source code here? myself do not download attachment from strange web sites.

Comment: With the added source the post goes to 317k characters, and the limit is 30k

Comment: ok, I changed the file to another upload host

Comment: Paste.bin is best for these cases. Nobody will like downloading executable codes from an upload site.

Comment: ok, added it to pastebin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in symbolic processing code of `NIntegrate` and `Integrate` in version 10 (the same bug appears with `Integrate`). One workaround is to disable symbolic processing by integrating a "black-box" function instead of the actual function:

```
intfunc = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/vQK1U0xZ", "Package"];
f[t_Real] = intfunc'[t];
NIntegrate[f[tt], {tt, 0, 1627577.2}, Method -> "Oscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in tt near {tt} = {349671.99051049186008855806291520295494990982872420}. NIntegrate obtained 0.057331917380647974851033238907542786073579734962061`50. and
> 4.5174922699302067733913885651850484430861561149963`50.*^-9 for the integral and error estimates. >>

> ```
> 0.057331917380647974851033238907542786073579734962061
> ```

The same result can be achieved by switching off symbolic processing via the `Method` option:

```
NIntegrate[intfunc'[tt], {tt, 0, 1627577.2}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

---

It is interesting that explicit `Method -> "Oscillatory"` is sufficient to avoid the bug:

```
NIntegrate[intfunc'[tt], {tt, 0, 1627577.2}, Method -> "Oscillatory"]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in tt near {tt} = {352828.}. NIntegrate obtained 0.05733276909199948` and 7.840132211343309`*^-7 for the integral and error estimates. >>

> ```
> 0.0573328
> ```

Comment: whoa! I didn't knew you could import `pastebin` samples directly into Mathematica. So smooth